Odoo 14: Clearing related records on onchange does not remove database entries
I am working with Odoo 14 and facing an issue where I am unable to clear related records in the database when changing a selection in a form view. I have an onchange method that is supposed to clear existing routing_line_ids when the routing_id changes, but it seems that the database records are not being removed as expected.
@api.onchange('routing_id')
def onchange_routing_id(self):
    if self.routing_id:
        # Clear existing routing_line_ids
        self.routing_line_ids = [(5,0,0)]
        
        # Create new routing_line_ids data
        data_list = []
        for line in self.routing_id.line_ids:
            data_list.append((0, 0, {
                'process_id': line.process_id.id,
                'working_hours_minute': line.working_hours_minute,
                'prepare_working_hours': line.prepare_working_hours,
                'note': line.note,
            }))
        self.routing_line_ids = data_list
    else:
        # If routing_id is empty, clear routing_line_ids
        self.routing_line_ids = [(5,0,0)]

model：
class RokeRoutingOrderModel(models.Model):
    _inherit = "roke.routing"
    _description = "工艺设计订单"
    _rec_name = "task_code"

    task_code = fields.Char('任务号')
    product_id = fields.Many2one('roke.product', string='零件名称', limit=10)
    spec = fields.Char('型号')
    picture_number = fields.Char('图号')
    plan_code = fields.Char('计划号')
    order_qty = fields.Float('订单数量')
    work_qty = fields.Float('加工数量')
    production_date = fields.Date('投产日期', default=fields.Date.today())
    submit_date = fields.Date('计划交付日期', default=fields.Date.today())
    output_month = fields.Date('产值月份')
    is_on_time = fields.Boolean('是否按期交付')
    receive_time = fields.Datetime('接收图纸时间')
    priority = fields.Selection([("1级", "1级"), ("2级", "2级"), ("3级", "3级"), ("4级", "4级"), ("5级", "5级")],
                                default='1级', string="优先级")
    state = fields.Selection([('未开始', '未开始'), ('进行中', '进行中'), ('已完成', '已完成'), ('取消', '取消')],
                             string='状态', default='未开始')
    production_order_line_id = fields.Many2one('roke.production.order.line', string='生产订单明细')
    production_order_id = fields.Many2one(related='production_order_line_id.order_id', string='生产订单', store=True)
    is_write = fields.Selection([('创建', '创建'), ('已创建', '已创建'), ('已修改', '已修改'), ('已更新', '已更新')],
                                default='创建', string='更新标志')
    # 添加字段来显示总耗时
    duration = fields.Float(string="用时(天)", compute="_compute_duration", store=True)
    routing_id = fields.Many2one("roke.routing", string="工艺路线")
    # 添加字段来存储工艺路线的明细
    routing_line_ids = fields.One2many('roke.routing.line', 'routing_id', string='工艺明细')
    finish_time = fields.Datetime(string="完成时间", readonly=True)


Steps to Reproduce:
Change the routing_id in the form view.
The onchange method is triggered.
The routing_line_ids in memory are cleared.
However, the related records in the database are not removed.
Expected Behavior:
Upon changing the routing_id, all related routing_line_ids records in the database should be cleared.
Actual Behavior:
The routing_line_ids are cleared in memory, but the database records remain unchanged.
Environment:
Odoo Version: 14
Python Version: [Your Python version here]
Postgres Version: [Your Postgres version here]
Additional Information:
I have verified that the onchange method is being called correctly.
I am unsure if there are any specific steps or methods I need to follow to ensure that the database records are also cleared when the onchange method is triggered.

You can prepare data_list and assign the value of the field at the end of your function body. In both cases, it should contain (5,0,0)

The effect of the onchange changes is only recognised in the database once the record has been saved. If you change the routing_line_ids twice, the previous positions cannot be removed. The following change to the code is necessary:
@api.onchange('routing_id')
def onchange_routing_id(self):
    if self.routing_id:
        # Clear existing routing_line_ids
        data_list = [(5,0,0)]
        
        # Create new routing_line_ids data
        for line in self.routing_id.line_ids:
            data_list.append((0, 0, {
                'process_id': line.process_id.id,
                'working_hours_minute': line.working_hours_minute,
                'prepare_working_hours': line.prepare_working_hours,
                'note': line.note,
            }))
        self.routing_line_ids = data_list
    else:
        # If routing_id is empty, clear routing_line_ids
        self.routing_line_ids = [(5,0,0)]

So the change is to save every change at once, including the "clearing" operation.
